# Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing

Tags: java, jar

I have a runable jar file of a Java Application build with Maven.

When I try to run the that jar file 'java -jar myApp.jar`, I am getting below Exception:-

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'controller'
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:156)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:174)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:188)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:193)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:268)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:274)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:41)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the Jar from Eclipse (jar or runnable jar), created the jar from cmd using **mvn package**(Where pom file is present), and i got the target jar file and that's running.